# Bug in LinkedHashSet javadoc?

Tags: java, collections, set, javadoc, linkedhashset

Maybe I'm being picky, but in javadoc there is a following information about LinkedHashSet implementation:

> This implementation differs from
>   HashSet in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list  running through
>   all of its entries.

I can't find any double-linked list in LinkedHashSet class. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit wonky when you look at the source without drilling down.  Notice it calls that package protected HashSet constructor that takes a meaningless boolean called dummy:

```
public LinkedHashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
    super(initialCapacity, loadFactor, true);
}
```

That then uses a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` to back the set.  Effectively, LinkedHashSet is actually inside HashSet, it's just package protected so you have to use LinkedHashSet to get at it.

Answer (score 6):

The doubly-linked list is on the implementation side, not necessarily exposed for you to get and use.

It keeps the doubly linked list so it can keep track of the order your items are inserted into the set (and also for order of accessing elements in  [access-order LinkedHashMaps](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29)). A regular HashSet has no need for a doubly-linked list since it makes no guarantee about the order of its contents.

They probably included that bit in the javadoc just so you were aware of how they did it, and that there is a little more going on behind the scenes with a LinkedHashSet than a regular HashSet.

You can take a peek at the source code at [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OV-zwmL9vlY/gcc/libjava/classpath/java/util/LinkedHashSet.java&q=LinkedHashSet%5C.java&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) (you will notice that a LinkedHashSet is actually just wrapped around a [LinkedHashMap](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OV-zwmL9vlY/gcc/libjava/classpath/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java&q=LinkedHashSet%5C.java&d=5), but that's not a very important detail).

In the end, it's not a mistake in the javadocs and you shouldn't worry about the fact there is a doubly-linked list working within the LinkedHashSet and LinkedHashMap. We can just merrily take advantage of the LinkedHashMap maintaining order of insertion, paying no mind to what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: That what I mean. There is not list in implementation (source code) of LinkedHashSet

Comment: @Petro Semenuik That's because it uses a LinkedHashMap. I'll post the source for that too. That's where you'll see the bulk of the magic.

Comment: OMG! Why did they implement things in this way. Is there any design benefits?

Comment: @Petro Semenuik I'm not sure what you mean. They used the doubly-linked list to support the insertion order bits -- as well as support modifying the Map/Set based on access. As for wrapping the LinkedHashSet around a LinkedHashMap -- I guess they figured no point in writing the same code twice.

Comment: I mean why did they have LinkedHashMap creation in HashSet, not LinkedHashSet (as for wrapping the LinkedHashSet around a LinkedHashMap I agree that this is because of code share)

Comment: @Petro Semenuik I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean a HashSet being created in LinkedHashMap, or the other way around?

Comment: I mean LinkedHashMap creation in HashSet, for me logical solution would be to create LinkedHashMap in LinkedHashSet

Comment: @Petro Semenuik As far as I can tell, there is no LinkedHashMap made inside the HashSet source, but I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: In Sun JDK 1.6 (didn't check other versions) LinkedHashSet extends HashSet and the LHS constructors call a constructor in HashSet which instantiates the backing map as a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap. I believe this is what Petro is referring to. I would speculate Sun did this because the rest of the methods in the HashSet class are merely actions on the backing Map - without any need to call implementation-specific methods - so there is no reason to duplicate this code in both HashSet *and* LinkedHashSet.